# Roboto Font not working in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I tried to use custom font in Xamarin iOS using [this guide](https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/). I added the fonts to Resources/Fonts folder. And then added it to the  info.plist under the array property `Fonts provided by application`. I changed the property of font to Bundle Resource and Copy Always.

Now, the newly added font have to be shown in xamarin designer. But, it is not showing for `Roboto-Regular.ttf`. But It is working fine for `OpenSans-Regular.ttf`.

Any help are welcome!

Comment: I have similar issues with the xamarin designer, I have to open the files with xml editor set the font name manually and reload the ui designer... driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

iOS may register the font under different font name. If your font was successfully registered (as your steps indicate you did), you can find it inside **UIFonts.FontFamilyNames** array and then use that. To find all registered fonts,

```
foreach (var fontFamily in UIFont.FamilyNames)
{
    foreach (var font in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(font))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

if you still don't see your font. Try to find it explicitly by name,

```
foreach (var font in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(friendlyFontName)) // can have space in font name.
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Console.WriteLine(item);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Console.WriteLine("---");
```

If you find your font there, that's what you need to use as font name in your code.

Example,

I recently used **Bbas Neue**. The file names where,

- BebasNeue Regular.ttf
- BebasNeue Bold.ttf
- BebasNeue Thin.ttf

In android, I used **BebasNeue Regular.ttf#BebasNeue Regular** and it worked as expected. In iOS, however, the font names were as follows,

- BebasNeueRegular
- BebasNeueBold
- BebasNeue-Thin

as you can see, not in any pattern. So after looking for font family **Bebas Neue** (with the space), I found the correct names, and was able to use the font on iOS.

Hope this helps.